# Use OpenVpnAdapter build MacOS client, but print error "cannot open available utun device"

Tags: openvpn, networkextension

Use OpenVpnAdapter build MacOS client, but print error "cannot open available utun device"

`openVPNAdapter handleError isOpen = 1 Error Domain=me.ss-abramchuk.openvpn-adapter.error-domain Code=21 "OpenVPN fatal error occured" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=OpenVPN fatal error occured, me.ss-abramchuk.openvpn-adapter.error-key.message=utun_error: cannot open available utun device, me.ss-abramchuk.openvpn-adapter.error-key.fatal=true, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error creating TUN/TAP interface.}`

I add network extension (app) in xcode project, has correct code sign and profile.

Cosole.app also shows handshake is succeed.